# Rails Paperclip: Timestamped processor using Video url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, paperclip

Currently I have a configuration for video upload as follows:

```
has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    timestamped: { processors: %i[ timestamper ] },
    small: ['640x', :jpeg],
    medium: ['750x', :jpeg],
    large: ['1242x', :jpeg]
  }
  validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo/
  process_in_background :video
```

In the above process an original video accompanied with thumbnails as defined in styles and a timestamped video is uploaded.
the timestamper is a separate rb file which adds timestamp with each frame of video.

Over here I want to upload the timestamped video using a video url rather than uploading both original video and paperclip converting it into a timestamped video.

The original video will be uploaded and I will be getting a url. Now I just want to upload the timestamped video using the video url only.

Is it possible !

Thanx